# Google creates URLs that do not exist

Tags: php, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I have a page like this:

```
mysite.co.uk/product.php?id=34-Name-of-the-product
```

the url is rewritten like:

```
rewritecond %{THE_REQUEST} \s/+product\.php\?id=([^\s&]+)&name=([^\s&]+) [NC]
rewriterule ^ %2/%1? [R=301,L]
rewritecond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
rewritecond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
rewriterule ^([^/]+)/([^/]+)?$ /product.php?id=$2&name=$1 [L,QSA]
```

which give me the following url:

```
mysite/Name-Of-the-product/34
```

which is what i want, however on this page there are some links to other product pages
like this:

```
<a href="http://www.mysite.co.uk/product2/35>link to product</a>
```

now google is making up the following url:

```
mysite.co.uk/Name-of-the-product/product2/35
```

as you can see it looses the number of the first product.
Is there a way to stop google doing this?

There are other url redirect in the .htaccess file like this (as I am no expert at all in.htacces I'm not sure if that is correct, if you spot an error please let me know)

```
rewritecond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www.mysite2.co.uk$ [OR]
rewritecond %{HTTP_HOST} ^mysite2.co.uk$
rewriterule ^detailed_page\.php(.*)$ "http\:\/\/www\.mysite\.co\.uk\/product\.php$1" [R=301,L]
rewritecond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www.mysite2.com$ [OR]
rewritecond %{HTTP_HOST} ^mysite2.com$
rewriterule ^detailed_page\.php(.*)$ "http\:\/\/www\.mysite\.co\.uk\/product\.php$1" [R=301,L]
rewritecond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www.mysite.co.uk$ [OR]
rewritecond %{HTTP_HOST} ^mysite.co.uk$
rewriterule ^detailed_page\.php(.*)$ "http\:\/\/www\.mysite\.co\.uk\/product\.php$1" [R=301,L]
```

Any help welcome

Comment: So Google inserts additional product names into your URL? I can't see a missing number, but an additional name. I'm not sure I did understand you correct.

Comment: It is missing the number of the first product 34, so what you'll expect would be: mysite.co.uk/Name-of-the-product/34/product2/35 (which is wrong anyway) but it chops the /34 of the original product.

Comment: Google, as far as historical experience can vouch for, does not alter URLs that it finds on pages - it keeps links as it finds them. Are you certain you don't have bad links on your site anywhere? You could get (or write) a simple link crawler to enumerate all of the links on your site to test this idea - just to be safe =]